# Array dimensions error with scipy solve_ovp

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to solve a boundary-value [problem](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT2425/Documents/Solving_Differential_Equations_In_R_Soetaert_K.pdf), pg. 221, with Scipy `solve_bvp`. The code is

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

def fun(x, y):    
    tmp = np.vstack(( np.cos(y[2]), np.sin(y[2]), y[3], (y[4]*np.cos(y[2])), 0 ))
    return tmp

def bc(ya, yb):
    tmp = np.array([   ya[0], ya[1], ya[3], yb[1], yb[2]+(np.pi/2) ])
    return tmp

x = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 400)
y = np.zeros((5, x.size))

sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y)
```

I am getting an error

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Any ideas for the source? A simple problem works without an error

```
def fun(x, y):
    tmp = np.vstack((y[1], -np.exp(y[0])))
    print (tmp)
    return tmp

def bc(ya, yb):
    tmp = np.array([ya[0], yb[0]])
    print (tmp)
    return tmp

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)

y_1 = np.zeros((2, x.size))

from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
res_1 = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y_1)
```

Comment: The `errror` should have given you a `traceback` showing exactly were it occurs.  But only you can see that; we can't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0 in `np.vstack(...,(y[4]*np.cos(y[2])), 0 ))` is the problem. It is not casted to the correct dimension.

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

def fun(x, y):    
    tmp = np.vstack(( np.cos(y[2]), np.sin(y[2]), y[3], (y[4]*np.cos(y[2])), np.zeros(y[3].shape) ))
    return tmp

def bc(ya, yb):
    tmp = np.array([   ya[0], ya[1], ya[3], yb[1], yb[2]+(np.pi/2) ])
    return tmp

x = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 400)
y = np.zeros((5, x.size))

sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y)
```

runs without issues.